# Double function segmentation fault on return to double

Tags: c++, function, segmentation-fault, double

I have a double function

```
double Grid::getAverageNeighborhoodFitnessEvaluation(int agentPositionX, int agentPositionY)
{
  GetNeighbourhood(agentPositionX, agentPositionY,neighborhoodEvaluations);
  int neighborscount = 0;
  double fitnesssum = 0;
  double neighborfitness;
  double value;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < neighborhoodEvaluations.size(); ++i)
  {
    if ((*(neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i))) != NULL)
    {
      neighborfitness = (*(neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)))->GetFitness();
      if(neighborfitness<0)
          neighborfitness=0;
      fitnesssum+=neighborfitness;
      neighborscount++;
    }
  }
  value = fitnesssum/neighborscount;
  return value;
}
```

GetNeighbourhood assigns an array of a defined type (Agent) to neighborhoodEvaluations

`*(neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)))->GetFitness();` returns a double that represents a value for that point in the array. These have all been used previously with no issues.

When called from my main (where RealX and RealY are two integers)

```
int currentFitness = getAverageNeighborhoodFitnessEvaluation(RealX,RealY);
```

always works

```
double currentFitness = getAverageNeighborhoodFitnessEvaluation(RealX,RealY);
```

causes Segmentation fault

Does anyone know what possibilities could result in this and/or what value an int can take but a double can't seem to?

So far i have traced the error to our Agent implementation

Agent.cpp

```
#include "Agent.h"

Agent::Agent(void)
{
    m_age = 0;
    m_fitness = -1;
}

Agent::~Agent(void)
{
}

int Agent::GetAge()
{
    return m_age;
}

double Agent::GetFitness()
{
    return m_fitness;
}

void Agent::IncreaseAge()
{
    m_age++;
}

AgentType Agent::GetType()
{
    return m_type;
}
```

Agent.h

```
#ifndef AGENT_H
#define AGENT_H

enum AgentType { candidateSolution, cupid, reaper, breeder};

class Agent
{
public:
    Agent(void);
    virtual ~Agent(void);

    double GetFitness();
    int GetAge();
    void IncreaseAge();
    AgentType GetType();
    virtual void RandomizeGenome() = 0;

protected:
    double m_fitness;
    AgentType m_type;
private:
    int m_age;
};
#endif // !AGENT_H
```

Can't seem to locate the exact problem though

Comment: Are you sure that `neighborhoodEvaluations.size()` is always greater than zero?

Comment: Whenever you get a "crash" such as segmentation fault, your first reaction should be to run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate _where_ the crash is, as well as let you examine variables to help you find out the _cause_ of the crash.

Comment: Your code will crash if it is zero because `value = fitnesssum/neighborscount;` is a division by zero in that case. Just step through and check it with your debugger.

Comment: @nabulke In fact, it is `0/0`, which should return `NaN`. Anything can happen as soon as you try to use that value.

Comment: Dividing by zero is perfectly valid for floating point numbers, so that won't cause a crash. But *neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i) looks a bit scary. I am tot sure exactly what neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i) returns, but if it is a pointer which you want to be non-null, it should be neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i) != NULL, not *neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i) != NULL.

Comment: Gorpik: No, NaN has perfectly well-defined semantics, so it isn't true that "Anything can happen" when you use it.

Comment: @amaurea: `.at(i)` will boundary-check, i.e. if the element does not exist, it will throw an exception. As for a `nullptr` element, that should not happen at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment on the gdb debugger answer, I see that you are calling the `GetFitness` method on a null object (`Agent::GetFitness (this=0x0)`). This means that `neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)` is returning a null-pointer. at() only checks for out of bounds, but if what was put into the array to begin with is a null pointer, `at()` won't help you. To guard agains this, you should change

```
if ((*(neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i))) != NULL)
```

into

```
if (neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i) != NULL)
```

If neighborhoodEvaluations is not supposed to contain null pointers, you will have to track down why `getNeighborhood()` is putting them there. Perhaps you are looking for out-of-bound neighbors for the elements at the edge of your set of points?

Comment: Tried this immediately you mentioned it first in the comments. Didn't make a difference :(

Comment: Well, your gdb output shows you that you are getting an Agent* which is NULL. But perhaps there is another problem in addition to this. You should never ever see this=0x0, as it means that you are trying to call a method on an object which doesn't exist. Could you post a gdb backtrace from when it crashes, this time after you made the change I suggested? Perhaps that will bring new information to light.

Comment: Backtrace

`#0  0x0804923e in Agent::GetFitness (this=0x0) at Agent.cpp:22
#1  0x08054476 in Grid::getAverageNeighborhoodFitnessEvaluation (this=0xbfff52dc, 
    agentPositionX=97, agentPositionY=9) at Grid.cpp:224
#2  0x0805400b in Grid::DoMovement (this=0xbfff52dc) at Grid.cpp:104
#3  0x0805702d in runEvolution () at main.cpp:36
#4  0x080584c4 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff344) at main.cpp:346`

Comment: This tells you that in getAverageNeighborhoodFitnessEvaluation, you are trying to call GetFitness on a non-existant Agent. I.e. neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i) is returning an Agent* that is NULL, as I said. Are you sure you made the change I suggested? How about making it this, to be sure:
Agent * agent = neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i); if(agent) { neighborfitness = agent->getFitness(); etc. }

Comment: I did. And just tried the above. No difference. From my tests, seems calls to getFitness() and everything defined in Agent.cpp, in any manner results in the error sometimes. I am including the Agent.cpp and Agent.h contents in the main question; perhaps you or anyone can tell if there's anything off with it

Comment: Finally found it. An Agent* was indeed returning NULL cos agentPositionX was being calculated wrong. FIXED. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

Quickly get started on gdb debugger using this article http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/  . Then tell us which line produces the segmentation fault .

Comment: `neighborfitness = (*(neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)))->GetFitness();`
Agent::GetFitness (this=0x0) at Agent.cpp.

The GetFitness function is Agent.cpp is
`double Agent::GetFitness()
{
 return m_fitness;
}`

And is initially -1

Comment: could you put std::cout<<neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)<<std::endl; just before the line you mentioned and check if you see a valid value just before segmentation fault .

Comment: so....`std::cout<<neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)<<std::endl;` before the line prints valid values and for some funny reason, no seg faults. Also tried `std::cout<<(*(neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)))->GetFitness()<<std::endl;` with the same thing happening

Comment: Is the input same every-time ?

Comment: no, very different. It's a grid (torus) of "Agents", they all have different "Fitness" and even that keeps changing. The positions on the grid also changes, so the inputs are very random

Comment: Then run the program several time , until the segmentation error comes and then see the value of `std::cout<<neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)<<std::endl;`  and `std::cout<<(*(neighborhoodEvaluations.at(i)))->GetFitness()<<std::endl;`

Comment: The code already loops and calls the function 1000s of times. I get no seg faults at all with the "cout's".....strange

Comment: No. once i remove the "cout" line, the segfault return